# Plotear solo algunos valores matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot

Tengo ploteado dos columnas de un Dataframe, una con las temperaturas máximas y otras con las temperaturas mínimas.

Lo que necesito es con otro DF que tengo, que solo me plotee las temperaturas que sean menores que las q tengo, el resto q no haga nada.

Explico la imagen q adjunto:
En rojo y azul mas clarito, temperaturas mínimas y máximas que marcan los límites.
En amarillo las temperaturas que tengo que plotear solo cuando sean menores a las que ya tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que no das tus datos, me invento unos que sirvan para ilustrar el procedimiento.

Genero unas seriesde máximos y mínimos al azar, así como otras temperaturas que irían "cercanas a los mínimos":

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

maximas = np.random.randint(20, 30, size=100)
minimas = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=100)
otro = np.random.randint(5, 15, size=100)
```

Creo un dataframe con las columnas "Maximas" y "Minimas" y otro dataframe aparte con las temperaturas de la lista `otro`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Maximas": maximas, "Minimas": minimas})
df_otro = pd.DataFrame({"temperatura": otro})
```

Se trata de quedarse con las temperaturas de `df_otro` que estén **fuera** del intervalo definido por las columnas "Maximas" y "Minimas" de `df`. Esto puede hacerse filtrando sus filas para tomar sólo las que no cumplan estar dentro del intervalo (lo que se puede evaluar con `.between()`).

```py
fuera_rango = df_otro[~df_otro.temperatura.between(df.Minimas, df.Maximas)]
```

Ahora podemos plotear el resultado para comprobar que se ha hecho bien (el plot es horrible, pero no es ese el punto en esta respuesta :-)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df.Maximas, "o-", color="red")
plt.plot(df.Minimas, "o-", color="blue")
plt.plot(fuera_rango.temperatura,  "s", color="orange")
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((16,3))
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias!